# CKSubscription(recordType:, predicate:, option:) is missing in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, xcode, cloudkit, swift4.2

How can I create CKSubscription instance for iOS 9 now??

Is iOS 9 dropped under Swift 4.2?

Comment: The method is deprecated for basic `CKSubscription`. Use one of the subclasses.

Comment: Does that mean you can't build an app for iOS 9 with Swift 4.2?